# PrettyFaces navigation on selectOneMenu change

Tags: jsf-2, primefaces, prettyfaces

I have an application using PrettyFaces and PrimeFaces. One page is accessed using the URL pattern `/#{ location : navigationBean.location }/#{ year : navigationBean.year }`.

On that page I have a `p:selectOneMenu` containing possible values for location. If I change this menu I want the page to be refreshed with the same year and the new location.

I've tested this using AJAX to set the location in the navigationBean and then pressing a `p:commandButton` with the outcome `pretty:view` (`view` being the url-mapping id). This works but I want to get rid of the button.

I've tried the following, but sadly the return String in the method doesn't perform a navigation.

The JSF:

```
<p:selectOneMenu value="#{navigationBean.location}">
    <p:ajax listener="#{navigationBean.navigate}"/>
    <f:selectItems value="#{locationBean.locations}"/>
</p:selectOneMenu>
```

Backing bean:

```
public String navigate(AjaxBehaviorEvent event)
{
    return (location != null) ? "pretty:view" : null;
}
```

The PrettyFaces config:

```
<url-mapping id="view">
    <pattern value="/#{ location : navigationBean.location }/#{ /\\d{4}/ year : navigationBean.year }/"/>
    <view-id value="/view.xhtml"/>
</url-mapping>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't return a navigation outcome from (ajax) action listeners. You can only return it from real action methods as used in `<h:commandButton action>`.

Use [`NavigationHandler#handleNavigation()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/faces/application/NavigationHandler.html#handleNavigation%28javax.faces.context.FacesContext,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29) instead.

```
public void navigate() {
    FacesContext context = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
    context.getApplication().getNavigationHandler()
        .handleNavigation(context, null, (location != null) ? "pretty:view" : null);
}
```

Comment: Nice thanks! For the record `ExternalContext#redirect()` didn't work with PrettyFaces. The clumsy code is a mistake on my behalf (missed a spot simplifying the example, updated my question).

Comment: You're welcome. The `ExternalContext#redirect()` only takes **real** URLs, not JSF view IDs or navigation outcomes, let alone PrettyFaces view IDs or navigation outcomes.

Comment: Explains a lot. I've edited your answer for sanity reasons (made it match the updated answer). Thanks again.